# What's a good audio player for musicians?

Tags: audio, music, media-player

Can you recommend any **free** audio players (for windows) which are well suited **for musicians**? Some of the features I'd like to see in a player are:

- change the pitch of a song (e.g. transpose songs in half-tone steps)
- change the playback speed
- loop a part of a song (A-B repeat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm currently using is [WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com/) with the [PaceMaker plugin](http://www.surina.net/pacemaker/).

The PaceMaker plugin allows to change the tempo or pitch (or both) of a song and has some other nice features (e.g. save settings for each song, remove vocals). The plugin should also work with the [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) player.

I guess there are also WinAmp plugins for repeating a part of a song (but so far I didn't need it).

Comment: There are such plugins, if you want.

Answer (score 7):

[Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) had plugins to do all the above last time I used it and runs on Windows.

Comment: I can't find any plugins (e.g. for pitch-shift, change playback speed).

Comment: Look harder, I've done both before on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Transcribe](http://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/overview.html?a=48) will do everything you've mentioned as well.  It's available for Windows, Linux and OSX.

Comment: It's not free.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software available that does everything you require. It is called [MPfm: Music Player for Musicians](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp4m/). It is free and open source (GPLv3). It requires the .NET Framework 4.0. Unfortunately it is only available for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[mTrax](http://www.terrasofta.com/Default.aspx) player for player for musicians . but its not  free

*Note: You should have some nice headphones or speakers to enjoy real effects of mTrax*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go wrong with [Sound Forge](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/products/soundforgefamily.asp).  It is an excellent tool. Intuitive and pretty straightforward.

[image]

Comment: Not free, which was emphasised in the question.

Comment: I guess I added the "free" part after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a windows mobile media player with A-B repeat function, you might want to try Rosseta Repeater.

Here is a snopshot for your review.
[img]http://www.rossetamobile.com/screenshots/RossetaRepeaterLarge.gif[/img]

It can be download from rossetamobile.com

I would like to see any recommends and reviews of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/).  It's free, open source, cross-platform audio software for multi-track recording and editing.

Use the Effect -> Change Tempo feature.